# Результат работы программы не соответствует результату, если набирать команды в консоли

Tags: python-3.x

Запускаю в среде Visual Studio или Anaconda одну и туже программу:

```
a = 777
b = 777
print('a is b ? ', a is b) #должно быть False
print('a == b ? ', a == b)
print( 'id(a)' ,id(a))
print( 'id(b)' ,id(b))
```

Получаю
True
True
и одинаковые id. 
Результат работы не соответствует описанию языка Python в стандарте.
Потом набираю этот же код в консоли и получаю правильный результат:

False
True
и разные id.

В чем секрет зарытой собаки?

Comment: Просто вы еще @Молодойеще :) Извините, не удержался :) Думаю, дело в том, что когда вы запускали консоль, а точнее интерактивный режим, в котором каждая команда выполняется построчно не происходило кэширования константы `777` из-за чего на каждом присваивании создавался новый объект с ссылкой на `777`. А когда же вы запустили `.py` файл, то интерпретатор оптимизировал код, сделав то кэширование

Comment: Что с Целочисленным кешем внутри Python?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171695/whats-with-the-integer-cache-inside-python/15172182#15172182

Comment: Вместо двух отдельных строчек наберите в консоли `a=777;b=777` в одной строчке — и тоже получится True. Никто не запрещает интерпретатору объединять одинаковые числа в один объект

Comment: На счет кеширования я все понимаю. И объяснения тоже понял. (доступно написано!). Получается, что в командном режиме (консоли) каждая команда запускается запускается как отдельная "программа" и потому не происходит кеширование. Правильно?

Comment: Выполнил в консоли код a = 777; b = 777  и print (a is b) получил в ответе False. Что-то не так в "датском королевстве"...

Comment: Используйте число меньшее 256 - тогда должно кешировать и в интерактивном режиме ;)

Comment: Не в маленьких числах вопрос.